# The composite of harmonic function and a orthogonal mapping is harmonic?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Show that if $u$ is harmonic over $\mathbb{R}^N$ and if $T:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ is a orthogonal mapping so $uoT$ is harmonic $\mathbb{R}^N$.

This is a question of my homework of the course of Partial Differential Equations. I don't know how to solve this and I have no idea how to start this so I asked a tip for the monitor of the discipline and he gave me this:

$$
u(T(x))=\frac{N}{\omega_NR^N}\int_{B_1(0)}(uT(x)+Ry)dy
$$

Still can not continue and feel that the monitor is too confusing to help me. Can anyone guide me better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint is to prove that $v = u\circ T$ has the mean value property (which characterizes the harmonic functions). Apparently, you are to use the ball-mean (not sphere-mean) here. So, the goal is to show that for every $x\in \mathbb R^N$ and every $R>0$ we have 
$$ v(x) = \frac{N}{\omega_N R^N} \int_{B_1(0)} v(x+Ry)\,dy \tag{1} $$
Make the change of variables $w = Ty$. Note that the Jacobian of this transformation $\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}$ is $\pm 1$, because $T$ is orthogonal (keep in mind that $x$ is not a variable here; $y$ and $w$ are). So, 
$$ \int_{B_1(0)} v(x+Ry)\,dy 
=  \int_{B_1(0)} u(Tx+RTy)\,dy = \int_{B_1(0)} u(Tx+Rw)\,dw \tag{2}
$$
Since $u$ is harmonic, the property 
$$
u(Tx) = \frac{N}{\omega_N R^N}\int_{B_1(0)} u(Tx+Rw)\,dw \tag{3}
$$
holds; and by (2), it implies (1).